# React Native function return the promise in JSX

Tags: react-native, es6-promise

I am trying to return the value using the function. If I console the `result` in the function, I get the value but if I use `distance`, it is not working. It returns as a promise. How to fix this issue in JSX? I can't use the `useState` because `ci_empAddressDetails` will come from the loop.

```
import haversine from 'haversine';
import { getCurrentLocation } from 'src/utils/helpers';
 const { data, style, handleSelect, bg } = props;
    const { am_accountNo, am_advArrAmt, am_avdArrDays, c_id, p_code, amtp_lastActionTaken, cusInfo } = data;
    const { ci_customerNameUnformatted, ci_empAddressDetails } = cusInfo[0];

const distance = useMemo(async () => {
        if (!isEmpty(ci_empAddressDetails)) {
            const { value } = ci_empAddressDetails[0];
            const { ci_latitude, ci_longitude } = value[0];
            const res = await getCurrentLocation();
            const end = {
                latitude: ci_latitude,
                longitude: ci_longitude,
            };
            const result = haversine(res, end, { unit: 'mile' });
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }, [ci_empAddressDetails]);
```

In Jsx I am returning the value

```
<View style={{ width: '30%', justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
                    <Text style={[styles.linkTo, styles.labelName]}>{!isEmpty(ci_empAddressDetails) ? distance : '-'}</Text>
                </View>
```

Comment: Why are you using console.log in JSX? Try to remove it.

Comment: @Jay for testing i added